# How do I change the NAMEDATALEN configuration after installing PostgreSQL 9.0?

Tags: postgresql

I'm supporting some legacy PostgreSQL 8.3/4 databases, and migrating them onto some newer Windows Server 2008 hardware.

I've been informed that the NAMEDATALEN figure needs to be higher than the default.

As far as I understand, the NAMEDATALEN configuration does not exist in a config file, but rather needs to be set on compiling the application.

Having already installed PostgreSQL 9.0 on the new box, I'm wondering if it's possible to alter this configuration after the fact?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to alter this option - it needs to be changed in source file `src/include/pg_config_manual.h`. Then Postgres needs to be recompiled, data directory initialized with `initdb` and data restored. Every security and bugfix minor release will then have to be patched and recompiled. This is bad thing to do.

This is much easier and sensible to patch an application source to use shorter table/function/etc names. The maximum is 63 characters, which is enough for   `insanely_stupid_and_totally_impractical_table_or_function_name0`

Maybe your schema really does not need longer names, and this requirement it is just an artifact from long gone version of your client application. Check this - try to import a schema and functions to new database.

And this question should probably be migrated to [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: it isn't however long enough to support a from which is a select. Thanks though.. :)

Comment: @baash05 I have no idea what are you talking about.

Comment: It's true that it's enough for column names but some ORM's generates a huge 'aliases' via 'AS'. And I'm just faced with such problem.

Comment: You can easily check the maximum length using `SHOW max_identifier_length;`. Note that the length is in bytes, so character length is less for multibyte encodings. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/runtime-config-preset.html .