# how to change Postgres Table Field name limit?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a table whose field name is of 100 characters but postgres limit for no of characters is 64 so how to change that limit to 100?

example:
Create table Test
(
PatientFirstnameLastNameSSNPolicyInsuraceTicketDetailEMRquestionEMR varchar(10)
)

This table creation fails as the name exceeds 64 characters

Comment: I wouldn't want to be the coder who needs to type that 100 character-long column name. :-)

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836247/how-do-i-change-the-namedatalen-configuration-after-installing-postgresql-9-0

Comment: @Denis: I've been known to copy much shorter column names from the SQL page of pgAdminIII. Fewer typos.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually name's limit is equal to `NAMEDATALEN - 1` bytes (not necessarily characters), default value for NAMEDATALEN is 64.

NAMEDATALEN was determined at compile time (in `src/include/pg_config_manual.h`). You have to recompile PostgreSQL with new NAMEDATALEN limit to make it work.

However think about design and compatibility with other servers with standard 63 bytes limit. It's not common practice to use such long names.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the [special `name` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-character.html) (see table 8.5), which is used in pg_catalog. It won't accept anything longer than 63 bytes (plus terminator). There is no workaround.

Comment: PostgreSQL is open source. There's *always* a workaround for open source software. But it's often not a pleasant one. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware, but I doubt the OP would get his hands that dirty. ;-)

Comment: Plus, 63 chars is, as noted in the other thread linked in comments, long enough to accept "insanely_stupid_and_totally_impractical_table_or_function_name0" :-D

Comment: Unless you care about namespacing your columns, in which case `data_management_program_unlist_undiscovered_venue_movie_even‌​ts_unlisted_at` is too long.