# Input string is longer than NAMEDATALEN-1 (63) Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem with renaming table in my Ruby on Rails application. I have model CarAddition and now I must rename it to AvailableCarAddition. So i write migration:

```
class RenameCarAdditionsToAvailableCarAdditions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :car_additions, :available_car_additions
    rename_column :car_additions_assignments, :car_addition_id, :available_car_addition_id
    rename_column :car_addition_translations, :car_addition_id, :available_car_addition_id
    rename_table :car_addition_translations, :available_car_addition_translations
  end
end
```

when i try to run it I have the following error:

```
Input string is longer than NAMEDATALEN-1 (63)/home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rentcar/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/quoting.rb:154:in `quote_ident'
```

This line causes the problem:

```
rename_table :car_addition_translations, :available_car_addition_translations
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836247/how-do-i-change-the-namedatalen-configuration-after-installing-postgresql-9-0 Short answer: you should choose a shorter table name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a limitation of PostgreSQL. At compile time the `NAMEDATALEN` constant defines the maximum length of an identifier. (By default it is 64). It cannot be changed without recompiling PostgreSQL.

**Most likely it is an index name** which is hitting the character limit. That's because since Rails 4 `rename_table` also renames the existing indexes and the auto-generated index names tend to get very long.

Currently it is not possible to disable the index renaming, but **you can circumvent it**:

Use `rename_index` to rename your index to anything different than the auto-generated name *before* calling `rename_table`. Because then the following `rename_table` will no longer touch the existing index.

That might be annoying, but you won't be able to keep your auto-generated index names anyway, you just have to rename them before renaming the table.

Comment: Can I just add refinement: I came across a slight variation on this problem. The first argument can cause this as well as the second. As far as I can tell it's caused by the PostgreSQL trying to read the index names and doing a sanity check.